# How to change line-break automatically without adding code

Tags: php

How I can change line break without adding `<br>` in the end of sentence like above that?

```
TAF WATT 301700Z 3018/3118 12005KT 8000 FEW020  
BECMG 3022/3024 9999=

TAF WIII 301700Z 3018/3124 VRB05KT 4000 HZ FEW020 SCT100  
BECMG 3101/3103 02010KT 8000 NSW SCT022=
```

Comment: read more about [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br) function;

Answer (score 0):

Since it is in php, for line break you can use '\n' or '\n\r'

echo "TAF WATT 301700Z 3018/3118 12005KT 8000 FEW020 \n BECMG 3022/3024 9999=";